# How to extract information and perform the same operation on multiple similar files in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have several hundred files, each of which represent prices for a particular stock, and I want to loop through them, calculate log return, and add the log return as a column in a data frame containing log returns for all of the stocks.

Essentially, I have something like this, say I have three csvs that are named "a.csv", "b.csv" and "c.csv", and they look something like (the numbers below are totally fabricated, the idea is just that the dates are not necessarily the same, nor are the files the same length, but they have the same columns and names):

a.csv:

```
Date    Adj.Close
1/1/2001    5
1/2/2001    5.25
1/3/2001    5.17
1/4/2001    5.09
1/5/2001    5.83
```

b.csv:

```
Date    Adj.Close
3/17/2005   17.85
3/18/2005   19.20
3/19/2005   18.55
3/20/2005   18.45
```

c.csv:

```
Date    Adj.Close
5/9/1995    25.39
5/10/1995   25
5/11/1995   25.83
5/12/1995   24.99
5/13/1995   28
5/16/1995   27.17
5/17/1995   26.95
```

I know how to calculate log returns for one file (the below works fine for one file):

```
setwd('my_wd')
data <- read.csv('a.csv')
attach(data) 
n = dim(data)[1] 
log_rtn = diff(log(Adj.Close))
```

That gives me a list of the log returns for the first csv. What I want to do (in pseudo code) is:

```
for file in my_wd:
 data <- file_name.csv
 attach(data) 
 n = dim(data)[1] 
 file_name_log_rtn = diff(log(Adj.Close))
```

in order to return lists of log returns named in the same was as the csv (in pseudo-output), something like (named after the file, as below):

a_log_rtn:

```
0.048790164, -0.015355388,-0.015594858,0.13573917
```

b_log_rtn:

```
0.072906771, -0.03444049,-0.005405419
```

c_log_rtn:

```
-0.015479571,0.032660782,-0.033060862,0.113728765,-0.030091087,-0.008130126
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Foreword: Do not use `attach`, you have nothing to gain from it and it is potentially harmful.*

Without access to your files I have not tested the code below but I would do something along the lines of it.
The trick is to use `lapply` to process all the files in a loop. I use it twice, one time to read in the data and the second to create a new column with the log returns.

```
olddir <- setwd('my_wd')

files_list <- list.files(pattern = "*\\.csv")
data_list <- lapply(files_list, read.csv)
data_list <- lapply(data_list, function(DF){
            DF[["log_rtn"]] <- c(NA, diff(log(DF[["Adj.Close"]])))
            DF
        })

# reset the old directory if you want
#setwd(olddir)
```

Note that the column `log_rtn` will have `NA` as the first value. You can change this to `0` if you want but I believe that the `NA` makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have read it into a list, but then I get this error

     Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "log_rtn", value = 
    c(0.0142219163645847,  : 
      replacement has 7074 rows, data has 7075

I think when it tries to assign the log returns to the first dataframe. I assume that is a function of the fact that log returns will always be one "row shorter" than the prices, and the first day should be NaN (since it is a difference from the prior day). I'm not sure how to implement that in this structure

Comment: @JohnDoe Ok, you are right, there is a bug. I will edit the answer.

Comment: thanks again for your help, one more question: I was getting an "unexpected }" error, so I added an extra parentheses to; 

DF[["log_rtn"]] <- c(NA, diff(log(DF[["Adj.Close"]])))=

but now I am getting the error "Error in DF[["log_rtn"]] <- c(NA, diff(log(DF[["Adj.Close"]]))) = DF : 
  could not find function "<-<-""

I thought <- as just assignment, so I am not sure where that error is coming from

Comment: @JohnDoe It was a typo, I accidently pressed the `=` key.

Comment: On the other hand, this seems to work fine (sorry for the formatting, I'm not sure how to modify code in the comments:

files_list <- list.files(pattern = "*\\.csv")
data_list <- lapply(files_list, read.csv)
data_list <- lapply(data_list, function(DF){
                                            DF[["log_rtn"]] <- c(NA, diff(log(DF[["Adj.Close"]])))
                                            })

Answer (score 2):

```
allfiles=list.files(path_to_the_files_here,pattern = "\\.csv")
listdata=lapply(allfiles,function(x)transform(read.csv(x),log_Adj.Close=log(Adj.Close)))
```

If you want you can list these to the environment:

```
list2env(setNames(listdata,gsub(".*(.)(\\.csv)","\\1",allfiles)))
```

Comment: Thanks! So this seems to create the dataframes in a list, which is cool, but it just takes log of adjusted close, what I am trying to get to is the daily log returns, which would be the difference in log of Adj.Close from day to day. The first day should be NaN (since there is no day 0). I am not sure how to implement this using this method.

Comment: Really easy. Just do diff_log=c(NA,diff(log(Ddj.Close))

Answer (score 1):

Put the files in a directory, say it is called `csv_dir`.

```
csv_list <- list.files(csv_dir, pattern = "csv", full.names = T)
names(csv_list) <- basename(csv_list)
log_diffs <- lapply(csv_list, function(t) {tcsv <- read.csv(t)
                                           diff(log(tcsv$Adj.Close)
                                            })
```

This will produce a list `log_diffs` with what you want. To see the results from a particular file you can use `log_diff[["a.csv"]]` for example. If you want to put all the results in one big data frame, with one column for the file name and another with the log differences, you could do the following:

```
log_diffs <- lapply(csv_list, function(t) {tcsv <- read.csv(t)
                                           data.frame(file = rep(basename(t)),
                                           log.diff = diff(log(tcsv$Adj.Close),
                                           stringsAsFactors = F)})

csv_log_diffs <- do.call(rbind(log_diffs))
```

If your csv files are very large, you could consider using `read_csv` from the `readr` package, it will be faster than `read.csv`, and provide a progress bar.